# Redirect to new page after coupon is applied in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I want to redirect my cart/checkout page to new page if coupon is applied in woocommerce.
I have a coupon for free print. If user applies it, I want the page to be redirected to a new page where user are given some products to choose.
I'm having great trouble to redirect the page after the coupon has been applied.
Any problemm would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

This is a javascript redirect with can be deployed anywhere in your php code

```
echo("<script> window.location = www.youradress.co.uk </script>");
```

For interest sake, this doesn't always work as if someone turns off their java (unlikely) it won't call, so you can use this which is a native php redirect

```
header("location:www.youradress.co.uk");
```

This has to be called before any html is created, including comments though :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But could youhelp me to write the hook which checks what coupon have been applied and then redirect to the page.

Comment: Hi all,
I think i got what i need but i need some help on other issue. I want only one product to be added to cart from the caterory( i.e Free Print Category). If any product from the category is in the cart. 
client's must have to remove that in order to add another item.
Could you please help.